# How do I make sure my if funtion runs before my data is pushed to a database?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, firebase

Hi this both these lines of code run and execute perfectly (tested with console logs) but for some reason, the data seems to get pushed to the database before this.state.weight is divided by 2.2 does anyone know why I tried a .then statement but that cause a compiling error whats the fix thanks in advance! :)

```
  calculate_bmi = () => {
        if (this.state.weightUnits === 'lbs') {

            this.setState({ Weight: this.state.Weight / 2.2 });
        }

        if (this.state.Gender !== '' && this.state.Age !== '' && this.state.Height !== '' && this.state.Weight !== '' && this.state.Goal !== '') {
            database.collection('Health_data').doc(localStorage.getItem('user')).set({
                gender: this.state.Gender,
                age: this.state.Age,
                height: this.state.Height,
                weight: this.state.Weight,
                goal: this.state.Goal
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message)
                console.log('failed to write', error);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please fill in all fields so we can get you started on your fitness journey!')
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your DB update check after you `setState()`, you can do so by using the callback provided as a 2nd argument to `setState()`. In addition, you could benefit from making your DB update condition + call a function.

Example:

```
calculate_bmi = () => { 
  // This comparison also feels unsafe, can the person accidentally save twice and divide the now kilogram weight again by 2.2?
  if (this.state.weightUnits === 'lbs') {
      this.setState(
        { Weight: this.state.Weight / 2.2 }, 
        // Callback performed AFTER the state gets updated
        () => this.saveData()
      );
  } else {
    this.saveData();  
  }
}

saveData = () => {
    if (
        this.state.Gender !== '' && 
        this.state.Age !== '' && 
        this.state.Height !== '' && 
        this.state.Weight !== '' && 
        this.state.Goal !== ''
    ) {
      database.collection('Health_data').doc(localStorage.getItem('user')).set({
          gender: this.state.Gender,
          age: this.state.Age,
          height: this.state.Height,
          weight: this.state.Weight,
          goal: this.state.Goal
      }).catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message)
          console.log('failed to write', error);
          return false;
      });
  } else {
      alert('Please fill in all fields so we can get you started on your fitness journey!');
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

[React setState() docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: I was very confused by your first statement but I now understand what you mean a double press of the button will divide it by 2.2 twice which could be a big issue but I intend to redirect the page after the button is pressed how else would you recommend to do this?

Comment: Since you are always storing the weight in kg, you could perform the conversion when you are visually rendering the weight from kg to lbs (if user prefers lbs) and when the user enters a new weight/updates existing you could have a function to handle the update in your state. This should ensure that you are always in kg in your state and you could avoid needing to convert before your DB update altogether. Your current approach should be okay though, without seeing more of your code, you likely already handle converting to lbs for display so my suggestion might be complicating things.

Comment: your suggestion would work calculating BMI and calorie requirements on the database using kg that's why I wanted it in kg form before uploading. your way of doing things would definitely work

Answer (score 2):

Caused by the fact that React will run the function setState but won't wait for the result and will execute the next lines. So while your state is updating, your second if will be triggered and without the correct data.

```js
calculate_bmi = () => {
  let weight = this.state.Weight;
  if (this.state.weightUnits === 'lbs') {
      weight /= 2.2;
      this.setState({ Weight: weight });
  }

  if (this.state.Gender !== '' && this.state.Age !== '' && this.state.Height !== '' && this.state.Weight !== '' && this.state.Goal !== '') {
      database.collection('Health_data').doc(localStorage.getItem('user')).set({
          gender: this.state.Gender,
          age: this.state.Age,
          height: this.state.Height,
          weight: weight, // change the variable you are sending
          goal: this.state.Goal
      }).catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message)
          console.log('failed to write', error);
      });
  } else {
      alert('Please fill in all fields so we can get you started on your fitness journey!')
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did'nt seem to work its still written to the data base in the lbs measurement. but the theory behind what you're say is sound

Comment: Looks like I forget to change the variable in the data you're sending to database. Take a look, and tell me. `weight: this.state.weight` became `weight: weight`.

Comment: doesnt work cant have weight: this.state.weight for some reason thanks though